# Why do I still get "N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details." weeks after

Tags: ubuntu-20.04

Few weeks ago I tried to install an IDM replica on Ubuntu 20.04 from Focal. However I got an error and from ever since, whenever I run "Sudo apt update" the same error returns.

Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu focal Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
[Screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfzHN.png)

Comment: Q: Have you tried commenting out the offending repos from your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Comment: No I haven't, thank you, I am new to Linux so I don't understand much but I am going to try.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```bash
sudo apt clean
cd /var/lib/apt 
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt update
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.